# listen to database insert and send push notification to android devices

Tags: php, android, push-notification

i want to send push notification to all my devices when there is an insert into table. i successfully developped a php script to send push notification.Now, i want to know how to detect the insert into one of my table. i'm asking for ideas.NB: leater this script will be executed in a cron mode.

Comment: you could use a trigger.

Comment: thank you for your help, if you have an example can you post it please

Comment: you could query for a new row, maybe by just checking the index. But this will be computationally intensive probably.

Comment: You can take a look [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php)  (it's an example in mySQL)

Comment: i have an idea how about counting the number of row and compare it to the last one? maybe it's a stupid idea

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions I can think of:

- Make a thread that does a select after an x amount of time.
- Use Sockets, so on the server side it sends a message to the client after a successful insert into the database.

Comment: this is my idea and i want to know if it can be correct or not. how about counting the number of row and compare it to the last one? but how and where to save this number

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name, will return the number of rows in table_name, to store the number you can use preferences http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html, after that you can compare the number after an x amount of time.

Comment: i prefere to make all the work in the server not the client (android)

Comment: what program/class/method is doing the insert?  Could you not attach some code to that function and push notifications out when the insert occurs?   Triggers are nice for this stuff